# How can I listen to a keystroke combination with lexical.js?

Tags: javascript, typescript, lexicaljs

I'm new to lexical.js and don't fully understand how I can listen to different keystroke combinations. I want to listen to "Ctrl/Cmd+S" and then fire off a callback (to save data). How can I do that?

With a textarea I can do something like:

```
const onKeyDown = (event) => {
  // "Ctrl" or "Cmd" + "s"
  if ((event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) && event.which === 83) {
    // save data
  }
}

<textarea onKeyDown={onKeyDown} />
```

With lexical I've tried to do something like:

```
const MY_SAVE_COMMAND: LexicalCommand<string> = createCommand('MY_SAVE_COMMAND')

editor.registerCommand<KeyboardEvent>(
  MY_SAVE_COMMAND,
  (event) => {
    console.log('[MY_SAVE_COMMAND] event', event)
    return true
  },
  COMMAND_PRIORITY_HIGH,
)
```

which does not work. Where do I insert the part where I listen to the keystrokes, or is there a different way of doing this altogether?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Custom commands are more like global event types. Lexical provides [a lot](https://github.com/facebook/lexical/blob/main/packages/lexical/src/LexicalCommands.ts) out of the box you can listen to, but for things like regular event listeners, what you probably want is to attach the event to the *rootElement* via [`editor.registerRootListener`](https://lexical.dev/docs/concepts/listeners#registerrootlistener).

You can use a custom plugin to manage attaching and removing this event listener. In the example below, I don't implement `onKeyDown`, but you would just like any other normal event handler.

```js
import {useLayoutEffect} from 'react';
import {useLexicalComposerContext} from '@lexical/react/LexicalComposerContext';

function CommandSPlugin() {
  const [editor] = useLexicalComposerContext();
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const onKeyDown = () => { /* Your handler logic here */ };

    return editor.registerRootListener(
      (
        rootElement: null | HTMLElement,
        prevRootElement: null | HTMLElement,
      ) => {
        if (prevRootElement !== null) {
          prevRootElement.removeEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown);
        }
        if (rootElement !== null) {
          rootElement.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown);
        }
      }
    );
  }, [editor]);
}

// Then later...

const initialConfig = { /* ... */ };
function App() {
  return (
    <LexicalComposer initialConfig={initialConfig}>
      <CommandSPlugin />
      <YourEditorHere />
    </LexicalComposer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for the answers they helped me a lot. Below the full solution I ended up using. I created a `<GlobalEventsPlugin />` with a `SAVE_COMMAND` command which can then be consumed by any plugin:

```
// GlobalEventsPlugin.tsx
import { useLayoutEffect } from 'react'
import { useLexicalComposerContext } from '@lexical/react/LexicalComposerContext'
import { LexicalCommand, createCommand } from 'lexical'

export const SAVE_COMMAND: LexicalCommand<KeyboardEvent> = createCommand('SAVE_COMMAND')

const GlobalEventsPlugin = () => {
  const [editor] = useLexicalComposerContext()

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const onKeyDown = (event: KeyboardEvent) => {
      // "Ctrl" or "Cmd" + "s"
      if ((event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) && event.which === 83) {
        editor.dispatchCommand(SAVE_COMMAND, event)
      }
    }

    return editor.registerRootListener((rootElement: HTMLElement | null, prevRootElement: HTMLElement | null) => {
      if (prevRootElement !== null) {
        prevRootElement.removeEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown)
      }
      if (rootElement !== null) {
        rootElement.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown)
      }
    })
  }, [editor])

  return null
}

export default GlobalEventsPlugin
```

```
// Editor.tsx
const initialConfig = { /* ... */ }
function App() {
  return (
    <LexicalComposer initialConfig={initialConfig}>
      <GlobalEventsPlugin />
      <YourEditorHere />
    </LexicalComposer>
  )
}
```

```
// Any other context that has access to `editor`
editor.registerCommand(
  SAVE_COMMAND,
  (event) => {
    // Do something with `event`, e.g. `event.preventDefault() && saveData()`
  },
  COMMAND_PRIORITY_HIGH,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Custom commands do not have automatic triggers: you must 'dispatch' them.**

From the [intro in the docs](https://lexical.dev/docs/intro#listeners-node-transforms-and-commands):

> Commands are the communication system used to wire everything together in Lexical. Custom commands can be created using `createCommand()` and dispatched to an editor using `editor.dispatchCommand(command, payload)`. Lexical dispatches commands internally when key presses are triggered and when other important signals occur. Commands can also be handled using `editor.registerCommand(handler, priority)`, and incoming commands are propagated through all handlers by priority until a handler stops the propagation (in a similar way to event propagation in the browser).

The built-in commands are dispatched in the same way.
If you look at the `LexicalEvents.ts` file (referenced frequently in the docs), you can see in the [function `onKeyDown`](https://github.com/facebook/lexical/blob/e2955005bb2db6d1a50b387dc032330d2e647459/packages/lexical/src/LexicalEvents.ts#L847) how their keyboard-triggered commands are implemented:

```js
function onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent, editor: LexicalEditor): void {
  ...

  const {keyCode, shiftKey, ctrlKey, metaKey, altKey} = event;

  if (isMoveForward(keyCode, ctrlKey, altKey, metaKey)) {
    dispatchCommand(editor, KEY_ARROW_RIGHT_COMMAND, event);
  } else if (isMoveToEnd(keyCode, ctrlKey, shiftKey, altKey, metaKey)) {
    dispatchCommand(editor, MOVE_TO_END, event);
  } ...
```

It uses helper functions to check the key and some of the modifier keys to determine if a certain combo was used, and, if so, dispatches the relevant command.

The pattern of including the original event is noted in the [docs for `dispatchCommand`](https://lexical.dev/docs/concepts/commands#editordispatchcommand):

> The `payload`s are typed via the `createCommand(...)` API, but they're usually a DOM `event` for commands dispatched from an event listener.

**Note:** if you use `Ctrl+S`, you'll need to use `preventDefault()` to prevent the browser trying to download the page.

Comment: I was missing the part where I can actually listen to the events via the `registerRootListener`. I haven't yet figured out commands but I think that's where I would then fire off the custom command so any other plugin can use it.

Answer (score 0):

There're two commands you can use:

- `KEY_DOWN_COMMAND` - Triggered on any key down event.
- `MODIFIER_KEY_COMMAND` – Triggered on key press if any modifier key (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>Alt</kbd>) is also pressed, which makes it a perfect match for shortcuts.